# Why won't my ajax call retrieve data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There is an email validation that I'm working on now.
Basically on a js event there is supposed to be the ajax call made sending data via post in json datatype, then the second ajax call is supposed to retrieve the data from the handler. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here are two short fragments of code.

jQuery

```
$(document).on('focuson',"input#signup_password_input",function(){
var this_user_input=$("input[name='signup_email_input']").val();
if ((error_one_passed==1)&&(error_two_passed==1)){
$.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });
$.ajax({
     url: 'ajax_email_validation.php',
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json',
     data: ({email_validation_ajax: "+this_user_input+"}),
     success: function(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ajax_email_validation.php',
                    data: data,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data1) {
                        var response_from_database=data1;
                    }
                });
            }
});  
}
});
```

php

```
include('mysql/database.php');
if (!isset($_POST["email_validation_ajax"])){$json_array = array('request' => error,    'response' => none);}
$dbcheck_email_validation=$_POST["email_validation_ajax"];
$dbcheck_email_validation=htmlspecialchars($dbcheck_email_validation);
$dbcheck_email_validation=mysql_real_escape_string($dbcheck_email_validation);
$dbcheck_email_validation_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$dbcheck_email_validation'",$db);
$dbcheck_email_validation_assoc=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbcheck_email_validation_query);
if (!empty($dbcheck_email_validation_assoc)){$json_array = array('request' => received, 'response' => negative);}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST["email_validation_ajax"])) {$json_array = array('request' =>   received, 'response' => affirmative);}
echo $_POST['email_validation_ajax'];
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

I would really appreciate if someone were able to help me out.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the focuson as a js event. I corrected that to focus, it still won't work.

Comment: You shouldn't be making two AJAX calls. Your first call should submit your data and retrieve the response from your PHP script. That response is passed to your `success` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You requested json, then didn't return json. instead you returned some plain text + some json.

```
echo $_POST['email_validation_ajax'];
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

you should instead just return json.

```
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

You also only need to perform the ajax call once.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_email_validation.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        email_validation_ajax: this_user_input // << this was also incorrect
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var response_from_database = data;
    }
});
```